# Getting class property name in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write common function which get all or single class property name

```
public class MyClass
{
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public int TemplateCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Example:
In other method I need to call

```
var propertyName = MyClass.TemplateId.GetPrertyName(); // will Return TemplateId
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

Comment: I've searched and read through it. But I dont want to using Lambda expression because it is hard to read and understand. I think that i will use nameof function.

Comment: Sorry. This is only possible way if you want to pass it into function. Also, it is not hard to read. Lambdas are common C# element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the c# 6 `nameof` operator, you can write:

```
nameof(MyClass.TemplateId);
```

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)

Comment: can i make it as a function. 

public string GetPropertyName(<????? i dont know what type here> xxxxxx)
{
      return nameof( xxxxxx );
}

Comment: `nameof` is the function you want

Comment: i will use this function. Thank you all of you.